# Which is the Hash function with minimal collsion for strings with length < 255 Chars and relatively fast enough?

Tags: java, hash

We get Transactional Data with a transaction id of length < 255 chars and is always UNIQUE.

But the limitation here is we aren't allowed to store the transaction id in our database.

Hence to uniquely identify a transaction we thought of using a hash fn to generate a hash using transaction id as the input.

So that, we do not save duplicate transactions as it would corrupt the metadata that we want to calculate. Ex: Averages, Standard Deviations, etc.

For a large amounts of transaction data coming into the system, which is the hash fn you would recommend that has lower collision probabilty and is fast enough ?

By Fast enough i mean, generate a hash in < 100 ns.

The Provider of this transactions data hasn't faced the same problem cause they are the generators and we are the first consumers.

I also looked up a few answers on StackOverFlow which suggested that SHA-512 is a bit faster than SHA-256 on 64 bit systems.

Also, is there a better approach for solving this ?

Thank you

Comment: We'd need to know what the transaction IDs look like, what counts as "fast enough", what size and data type your hash is, and what the cost of collisions is. At the moment we don't have enough information.

Comment: I'd just use SHA-256 unless there is evidence that it is too slow.

Comment: why not have a chat with the people who comes with the requirement that you are not allowed to store the id. I guess they have been in this situation before.

Comment: Edited the question to provide more information based on comments. @JonSkeet Skeet

Answer (score 0):

<s>Do not (ab)use a hash function for this. Hashing is good for protecting passwords, or for hash maps, where you have a secondary criteria to validate, that an object is in fact the object you expect. But using a hash as a presumably unique key (when it is not guaranteed to be) is inherently risky.</s>

As corrently mentioned, the likelyhood for SHA256-collisions is infinitesimal, so you could do that, at a low risk.

Because a hash function does not (and can never) guarantee absolute non-collision, there might be alternatives.

Question: Can you store the transaction timestamp? - if so, you could couple the timestamp with a numeric postfix, to achieve an internal id (different from the transaction id you originally have). This is way superior to a hash, in terms of uniqueness. It comes with the benefit of being exceedingly fast. But you'd have to store that postfix with the original object to be able to reproduce this internal id.

Essentially what you need is a function to determine a (definetly) unique key from a transaction object, based on attributes that you are allowed to store. Assuming you are allowed to store the timestamp and a numeric postfix, the following example is a possible solution.

In case you get timestamp-collisions, you increase the numeric postfix, so you'd get:

```java
2020-02-18-14-26-15-420-0 (postfic here is -0)
2020-02-18-14-26-15-420-1 (postfic here is -1)
2020-02-18-14-26-15-420-2 (postfic here is -2)
2020-02-18-14-26-15-423-0 (postfic here is -2)
```

Here some transactions have arrived at the same time. However they are still uniquely identifiable.

Comment: Sorry, but using a (crypto-)hash for the information to get an id is a good practice. VCS like git rely on that. Imagine a solar flare hits the atmosphere during your id calculation and causes a bit to flip in your CPU so a wrong id is calculated. That's not impossible (ask a physican for that); it's only very unlikely -- but the probability for this event is still bigger than the probability for getting a SHA256-collission on 2 randomly chosen strings

Comment: This is true for two strings. It becomes increasingly more likely, the more elements are in the system. But it's true, the likelyhood is small for a relatively small number of players. See https://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/ from 2011. So the likelyhood is strongly depending on the bit length of the hash, and the dispersion of the algorithm. For SHA256 this is indeed highly improbable, see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47809/why-havent-any-sha-256-collisions-been-found-yet